# How to implement autosave for a web application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, design-patterns

I have a web page that contains a table wherein you can edit every cell content. The typical size of this table is about 12 columns and 40 rows. This page is typically used by teachers to encode grades here in our area. But our area sometimes has a poor connection, and what happens is sometimes, teachers would lose the encoding they did (they typically only save after encoding everything).

So right now, I am thinking of implementing an autosave feature. I think the solution I'm thinking of is straight-forward: every time a cell gets edited and then loses focus, do an ajax request to save the data. At least that's what I'm thinking.

My concern is since there's a lot of people using this at the same time, wouldn't that be too heavy, every edit, access the DB, and insert or update? And also, I've tried it a bit and the UI became a bit choppy when moving from one cell to another. My main question basically is, is there a pattern or guidelines I can use for implementing this?

Comment: Hey @g_b can you put stuff in **bold** and points that you think are important for this question ? I also asked a performance based question on React some time back and it got a good response possibly due to formatting. Here is the link for your reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61724883/speed-comparison-in-react-paginated-table-vs-scrollable-table-for-column-sort.

Comment: I'd suggest you save edits in localStorage on client, and push updates in batches based on timeout (like, 5 seconds without edits) or user action (like, clicked 'Save')

Comment: maybe you need to read about https://redux.js.org/ . You can store table state and at some point submit that data. Not spec in this area though

Answer (score 1):

I'd need more details on what your api design to help come up with the most optimal solution but here are some high level approaches you can consider

1. On each cell update only update the diff (the exited cell) and not the entire dataset to keep the api call as light weight as possible
2. Look into using IndexedDB or Local Storage to save a copy of the data in the browser as they update cells. In case of a lost connection you can restore the user's session.

Answer (score 0):

There are some points here for your problem that I mentioned and try to say its solution:

First, you have to think about concurrency. If you need to show table content for a long time to your users, It is possible to change contents by other users at the same time, and the current content will expire! So you could keep your table content update continuously! one solution is to use [RowVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/concurrency?view=aspnetcore-5.0) in DotNet For this purpose (Optimistic approach for concurrency). Another solution is using [SingnalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) to keep tables update all the time (I mean Real Time).
In addition, there is no serious problem with update and edit according to a user request in regular systems but in an enterprise solution you can scale up or scale out your structure.